# Connection refused from localhost in wsl2 ubuntu

Tags: networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, firewall

I try to test connection between `windows 11` and `wsl2 ubuntu` in windows 11. First I install nginx on `wsl2 ubuntu` and type in 'localhost' on web browser on `windows 11` . The connection is successful. And next I install tomcat on `wsl2 ubuntu` and open the 8080 port with the following command on `wsl2 ubuntu`

```
> sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp
```

And I make inbound rule which permit 8080 port on `windows 11` firewall. But the connection was refused. How can I make the connection allowed between `windows 11` and `wsl2 ubuntu`?

Comment: WSL2 doesn't use a firewall like ufw unless you enabled systemd. You probably need to edit your Tomcat configurations to make it listen on 0.0.0.0 (which means all interfaces not just localhost)